# RxJava combining singles for local and remote data source

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

I am trying to create an observable that can emit data from both a `local` data source and a `remote` data source.
The remote one might have to wait due to connectivity not being available, in this case I have to wait until the connection comes back and then retry. In the meantime I should deliver local data immediately if available. 
Both local and remote can also deliver errors of course (data not cached, http error, ...)

Subscribing to the observable returned by `combineObservables` works as intended, however I would like to know if anyone knows a better way of doing this or can spot any issues with my code.

```
val local = localDataSource
            .getData(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

val remote = remoteDataSource
            .getData(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

fun <T: Any>combineObservables(local: Single<T>, remote: Single<T>) : Observable<T> {
    return Observable
            .interval(0, NETWORK_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_RATE_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter { connectivityChecker.check() }
            .take(1)
            .flatMap { remote.toObservable() }
            .startWith(local.toObservable())
            .debounce(DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```